# Journal has aborted ext4

Tags: ext4

Hi in my CentOS guest in VirtualBox I just realized, that my FS is mounted as readonly.

From `dmesg` I got:

```
[ 1725.767566] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_ext_remove_space:3028: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.767736] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_ext_truncate:4659: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.767889] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4977: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.768037] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_truncate:3865: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.768190] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4977: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.768358] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_orphan_del:2675: Journal has aborted
[ 1725.768362] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[ 1725.768368] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 1725.768495] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4977: Journal has aborted
```

Not really sure what happened.

I pasted full dmesg to http://codepad.org/ucIJZXmC

Answer (score 3):

The kernel is reporting ATA disk errors:

```
[ 1719.649797] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[ 1719.649805] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE
[ 1719.649820] ata1.00: cmd e7/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 2
         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 1719.649828] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1719.649847] ata1: hard resetting link
[ 1719.956121] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 1719.956802] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1719.956808] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xe7 Emask 0x4
[ 1720.755202] ata1.00: FLUSH failed Emask 0x1
[ 1720.755211] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1720.755293] ata1: EH complete
```

After several of these, the filesystem driver will abort the journal and switch to read-only mode. On a physical system, these errors normally indicate a disk hardware failure.

```
[ 1725.742159] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.

[ 1725.768368] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 1725.768495] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4977: Journal has aborted
[ 1896.091367] ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[ 1896.091375] ata1.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
```

But since this happens in a VirtualBox guest VM, there might be other reasons for it. For example, is the VM on removable media that has accidentally been unplugged?

Or is the disk that physically contains the VM's disk image actually failing?

Or do you have an antivirus software on the host system that attempts to check the VM's disk image for viruses, and so causes delays to the write operations?

Comment: Great but what then is the solution?! This "answer" leaves several unanswered questions and one might argue that it would have been better as a comment.

Comment: @NelsonGon: It was too long for a comment as I felt it was necessary to quote the important parts of the `dmesg` output. I hoped the original poster would edit his post to add more information so I could complete it, but it looks like that did not happen. At least there are a few suggestions to check in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I keep getting this error. I think it's a USB issue or something. I was able to boot up but this happens often since Kernel 5. Your answer however helped me to think about a different solution: Drive error.